# WIndows Gitlab-runner: Failed to requeue the runner

Tags: windows, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a pipeline with **2 jobs**.

I start user as super user on **windows** with debug mode and received next output:

```
Checking for jobs... received                       job=24173 repo_url=https://scm-01.oursite.com/theproject/theproject-tests.git runner=ub7wf5mg
Failed to requeue the runner                        builds=1 runner=ub7wf5mg
Running with gitlab-runner 12.8.0 (1b659122)        job=24173 project=789 runner=ub7wf5mg
  on vm14rkwEggplant ub7wf5mg                       job=24173 project=789 runner=ub7wf5mg
Shell configuration: environment: []
dockercommand:
- PowerShell
- -NoProfile
- -NoLogo
- -InputFormat
- text
- -OutputFormat
- text
- -NonInteractive
- -ExecutionPolicy
- Bypass
- -Command
- '-'
command: powershell
arguments:
- -noprofile
- -noninteractive
- -executionpolicy
- Bypass
- -command
passfile: true
extension: ps1
  job=24173 project=789 runner=ub7wf5mg
Using Shell executor...                             job=24173 project=789 runner=ub7wf5mg
Waiting for signals...                              job=24173 project=789 runner=ub7wf5mg
No referees configured                              job=24173 project=789 runner=ub7wf5mg
Executing build stage                               build_stage=prepare_script job=24173 project=789 runner=ub7wf5mg
Executing build stage                               build_stage=get_sources job=24173 project=789 runner=ub7wf5mg
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=1
WARNING: Failed to parse "X-GitLab-Trace-Update-Interval" header  error=strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax header-value= job=24173 runner=ub7wf5mg
Appending trace to coordinator... ok                code=202 job=24173 job-log=0-536 job-status=running runner=ub7wf5mg sent-log=0-535 status=202 Accepted update-interval=0s
Executing build stage                               build_stage=upload_artifacts_on_failure job=24173 project=789 runner=ub7wf5mg
Skipping referees execution                         job=24173 project=789 runner=ub7wf5mg
WARNING: Job failed: exit status 1                  duration=4.9592837s job=24173 project=789 runner=ub7wf5mg
WARNING: Failed to parse "X-GitLab-Trace-Update-Interval" header  error=strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax header-value= job=24173 runner=ub7wf5mg
Appending trace to coordinator... ok                code=202 job=24173 job-log=0-2526 job-status=running runner=ub7wf5mg sent-log=536-2525 status=202 Accepted update-interval=0s
Submitting job to coordinator... ok                 code=200 job=24173 job-status= runner=ub7wf5mg
WARNING: Failed to process runner                   builds=0 error=exit status 1 executor=shell runner=ub7wf5mg
```

Output of pipeline in gitlab is next:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.8.0 (1b659122)
  on vm14rkwEggplant ub7wf5mg
Using Shell executor...
Running on KS-IDE-TS4...
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/GitLab-Runner/builds/ub7wf5mg/0/ourproject/ourproject-winappdriver-tests/.git/
From https://scm-01.ourproject.com/ourproject/ourproject-winappdriver-tests
 * [new ref]         refs/pipelines/5813 -> refs/pipelines/5813
Checking out c924c09b as master...
warning: failed to remove packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.4.0/tasks/net472/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll: Invalid argument
warning: failed to remove packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.4.0/tasks/net472/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll: Invalid argument
warning: failed to remove packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.4.0/tasks/net472/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll: Invalid argument
warning: failed to remove packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.4.0/tasks/net472/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll: Invalid argument
warning: failed to remove packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.4.0/tasks/net472/System.Buffers.dll: Invalid argument
warning: failed to remove packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.4.0/tasks/net472/System.Collections.Immutable.dll: Permission denied
warning: failed to remove packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.4.0/tasks/net472/System.Memory.dll: Permission denied
warning: failed to remove packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.4.0/tasks/net472/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll: Permission denied
warning: failed to remove packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.4.0/tasks/net472/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll: Permission denied
warning: failed to remove packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.4.0/tasks/net472/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll: Permission denied
warning: failed to remove packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.4.0/tasks/net472/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll: Permission denied
warning: failed to remove packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.4.0/tasks/net472/VBCSCompiler.exe: Invalid argument
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

If I restart the runner the first job became succesefull, but the secound one fails again with very similiar error.

The git version is 
**git version 2.25.1.windows.1**

Is there any workaround for this issue? If downgrade of runner could help me?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I had a running process with a location in my repository. First, I kill it manually and the job started to work properly. Then I deleted this package at all from my solution and started to use the same file but from outside of the repository.

It was **VBCSCompiler.exe** file.

To try, you can first kill it manually from runner or by the cmd command:

```
 tasklist | find /i "VBCSCompiler.exe" && taskkill /im VBCSCompiler.exe /F \|| echo process "VBCSCompiler.exe" not running.
```

Then I delete the nuget package Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset, therefore this process path was changed to the

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn